# what is the distinction between an 'outer bag' and an 'inner bag' in pigLatin?

Tags: apache-pig

the manual/documentation uses the language of 'inner bag' and 'outer bag' extensively (say: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html  ), and yet I haven't been able to pin out clearly the precise definition separating the terms.

e.g. all inherently interrelated:

- If I give you a bag 'foo,' what would you need to know to label foo as an 'inner bag' vs. an 'outer bag'?
- Is 'any bag' who is not the most outer-bag then ' an inner bag' ?
- Are the labels of inner and outer always exclusive?
- In PigLatin, are all 'bags' 'relations' -- or is only 'the most outer bag' a relation?  (and inner bags are not relations)

to create a discussable example:

```
grunt> dump A;      
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(8,3,4)
(4,3,3)


grunt> W1 = GROUP A   ALL;         
grunt> W2 = GROUP W1  ALL;
grunt> W3 = GROUP W2  ALL;
grunt> W4 = GROUP W3  ALL;

grunt> describe W4;
W4: {group: chararray,W3: {(group: chararray,W2: {(group: chararray,W1: {(group: chararray,A: {(f1: int,f2: int,f3: int)})})})}}


grunt> illustrate W4;
(1,2,3)
---------------------------------------------------
| A     | f1:int      | f2:int      | f3:int      | 
---------------------------------------------------
|       | 1           | 2           | 3           | 
|       | 8           | 3           | 4           | 
---------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| W1     | group:chararray      | A:bag{:tuple(f1:int,f2:int,f3:int)}                          | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        | all                  | {(1, 2, 3), (8, 3, 4)}                                       | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| W2     | group:chararray      | W1:bag{:tuple(group:chararray,A:bag{:tuple(f1:int,f2:int,f3:int)})}                                         | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        | all                  | {(all, {(1, 2, 3), (8, 3, 4)})}                                                                             | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| W3     | group:chararray      | W2:bag{:tuple(group:chararray,W1:bag{:tuple(group:chararray,A:bag{:tuple(f1:int,f2:int,f3:int)})})}                                                        | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        | all                  | {(all, {(all, {(1, 2, 3), (8, 3, 4)})})}                                                                                                                   | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| W4     | group:chararray      | W3:bag{:tuple(group:chararray,W2:bag{:tuple(group:chararray,W1:bag{:tuple(group:chararray,A:bag{:tuple(f1:int,f2:int,f3:int)})})})}                                                                       | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        | all                  | {(all, {(all, {(all, {(1, 2, 3), (8, 3, 4)})})})}                                                                                                                                                         | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

grunt> dump W4;
(all,{(all,{(all,{(all,{(1,2,3),(4,2,1),(8,3,4),(4,3,3)})})})})
```

amongst the bags - W1, W2, W3, W4  -- which is inner, which is outer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer bag is actually relation `A`. This is a little weird, but it'll become clear once you know what an inner bag is. Let's just look at `W1`, for readability, since having the nested bags does not change the answer.

Schema and output for `W1`:

```
W1: {group:chararray, A:bag{:tuple(f1:int,f2:int,f3:int)}}
(all,{(1, 2, 3), (8, 3, 4)})
```

We can see their is a field in `W1` named `A` which is a bag. This is an inner bag because the bag is a field in the relation.

Remember that bags are just **unordered sets of tuples**, and we can see this is the output for `W1`. Now, look at the output of relation `A`:

```
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(8,3,4)
(4,3,3)
```

Pig does not guarantee the order of these tuples (unless you `ORDER` or something).  So, if you think about it, relation `A` is really just an **unordered set of tuples**. This is an outer bag.

You can find some examples of this [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#bag).

Comment: this helped,  thx.    I think I'm now getting it: the bag who is contained in no other bag is 'the outer bag'; and also happens to be 'the relation.' If it contains any bags, then each is 'an inner bag' (and not 'the outer bag').